# PHP Ratchet Push don't receive notification

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am trying to implement WebSocket in PHP by Ratchet following the documentation ([http://socketo.me/docs/push]). These are my pages

*bin/push-server.php*

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

*src/Pusher.php*

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {
    /**
     * A lookup of all the topics clients have subscribed to
     */
    protected $subscribedTopics = array();

    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
        $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
    }

    public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
        $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
        if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
            return;
        }

        $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

        // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
        $topic->broadcast($entryData);
    }
    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

*/post.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $entryData = array(
        'category' => "123",
        'title'    => "321",
        'category'  => "kittensCategory",
        'when'     => "2020-10-10",
    );
    $connotify = new mysqli("localhost", "usr", "psw", "db");
    $sqlnotify = "INSERT INTO `tb` (`cat`, `title`, `cat`, `status`, `time`) VALUES ('".$entryData['category']."', '".$entryData['title']."', '".$entryData['category']."', 'unread', '".$entryData['when']."', '') ";
    $exenotify = $connotify->query($sqlnotify);
    $connotify -> close();

    // This is our new stuff
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
```

*/page.html*

```
<html><body>
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cboden/fcae978cfc016d506639c5241f94e772/raw/e974ce895df527c83b8e010124a034cfcf6c9f4b/autobahn.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8080',
        function() {
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
</script>
</body></html>
```

I run in the terminal the file `bin/push-server.php` and apparently everything works without any error, the data is saved in my database and the terminal didn't display any error, however, `page.html` page does not display any information. What can be incorrect?

My operating system for testing and Windows 10, php 7.2.25. To `composer install` I used this example

*/composer.json*

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "react/zmq": "0.4.0"
    }
}
```

Thank you